# C# Response.Write Error from scaffolded "dotnet new mvc"

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm familiar with PHP and JS, as well as MVC methodology, but I'm completely new to C# and have spent time looking for the documentation on this specific error.

I used `dotnet new mvc` to create a working app on port 5000.  Also note, I am working in the Controller, not the model or view:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ExelonPrime.Models;

namespace OptimusPrime.Controllers{
    public class ApiController : Controller
    {
        public void Help_Pdf()
        {
            Response.Write("test");
        }
    }
}
```

And the error I get (when trying to compile) is:

```
error CS1061: 'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no accessible extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If I'm missing a `using` directive, which one is it?  I tried `System.Web` and that didn't work.  How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend following through microsofts tutorial on using asp.net core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

As far as this specific instance, rather than using `Response.Write`, I would do this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SampleWeb.Models;

namespace SampleWeb.Controllers
{
    public class ApiController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Help_Pdf()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

This specific [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2) might be helpful.

With this class, the url https://localhost:5001/api/Help_Pdf returns "test"

Comment: your code as written returns this error: `error CS0308: The non-generic type 'IActionResult' cannot be used with type arguments`.  Trying to add `[HttpGet]` above the method as in you link doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Sorry, you want the ActionResult<T> rather than IActionResult<T> (which doesn't exsit), updated the answer. @OliverWilliams

Comment: Sorry, having `[HttpGet]`, or `[HttpGet]`, or anything above the method returns a 404.  And it still doesn't output the string "test"

Comment: What url are you using to try to hit your endpoint? @OliverWilliams I'm going to update my answer with the full class

Answer (score 0):

In ASPNET Core, when writing an API, it's more common to return an object, or POCO in stead of directly writing to the response stream (although it indeed is possible)

try changing your

```
public void Help_Pdf()
{
    Response.Write("test");
}
```

to

```
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult Help_Pdf()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

this will return an 204 (no content), you can pass data however, to the OK function, to add a body to the response object.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work.  Returning `Ok()` doesn't change anything - still a 200 response.  Adding a string `Ok("test")` doesn't add the content.  And if I add your `[HttpGet]` line above, I just get a 404 returned.

Comment: `return OK();` actually returns 200, this behavior is by design: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I was just replying that the poster said it would return 204.  It doesn't.  And, adding `"test"` inside `Ok()` has no effect

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to write directly to the response stream like that, you can do this:

```
public async Task Help_Pdf()
{
    await Response.WriteAsync("Test");
}
```

However, I'd recommend not doing this in your actual app, the method should return an `IActionResult`. IMO it's not good practice to write directly to the stream in your controller methods (not very test friendly).

Comment: result when I try to build: `error CS1061: 'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'WriteAsync' and no accessible extension method 'WriteAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? It should tell if your missing any `using` statements. Does WriteAsync have a squiggly line under it? If not, try adding `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;`